# What benefit can be gained from finding total population size

Tags: sample-size, population, finite-population

I would imagine this has been asked before but I can't find it so feel free to link if you can!

Lets say I have a sample size of 100 and an unknown population size. There's a great deal I can learn from this sample about the total population, for example the mean of the sample is likely to be close to the mean of the population. However if I can then find the total population size does this give me new data. Specifically I can find the SIZE of the total population, but not the corresponding results for each unique entity in the population. In my case I expect the population size to be many orders of magnitude greater than the sample size, is this significant in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: There is a Finite Population Correction, but its effect will be tiny unless the sample is a reasonable proportion of the population. For the standard error it is

$    \text{FPC} = \sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}} $

Where n is your sample size and N is the population size. You can plug in various large numbers for N and see that FPC hardly changes and is always close to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It seems counter intuitive that no part of the statistics benefits from knowing the total population size. Just to clarify would knowing the population size suggest a required minimum sample size? I now assume not.

Comment: No, the minimum sample size is pretty much unaffected by the population size, unless the population is quite small.